# How to export table from flextable so that it matches how it looks on the RStudio viewer

Tags: r, flextable

I'm using the flextable package in RStudio to export my R output as a table onto a word document.

The table looks fine on the viewer:

[image: The table looks fine on the viewer:]

However, when I try to export this onto a word document it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the script I've used:

```
library(flextable)

table <- flextable(fct_count(a2, prop=TRUE))

table <- set_header_labels(table,
                        values = list(f = "Category") )

table <- theme_vanilla(table)
table <- autofit(table)

table

save_as_docx(
  "my table 1" = table, 
  path = "/path/to/file.docx")
```

Please help me figure out how to export so that it looks as it does on the viewer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to help without a reproducible example. I would play with width function until it works as I want. For example :

```
table <- width(table, j = c(1,3), width = c(2,4))
```